# What do shields do?

Tags: civilization-2

What is the point of the shields in your cities in Civilization II? I know that they are related to the amount of soldiers you can have, but how do I find out those numbers? They don't seem to be on the units themselves. Also, are they related to the city's defense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blue shields in the city view correspond to the production value of the city, they don't have anything to do with soldiers. This corresponds to how quickly the city can produce units and buildings.

Soldiers have separate shields that show their allegiance (by colour) and their health (by amount filled).

Comment: is that the only point of them?

Comment: @Johann Yes, but many tiles which give multiple production shields also confer defensive bonuses, particularly hills and forests.

Comment: There's a reason later Civ games use hammers and anvils. :D

Answer (score 0):

Shields are basically resource units. They *do* have something to do with soldiers, because each military unit requires "shields" to equip. For instance, militia cost ten shields, phalanxes, 20, musketeers 30, riflemen 40, etc.

Shields can also be used to build buildings or wonders. Each turn, a city's (net) production of shields (after waste and support) is added to what is being built, until there are enough accumulated shields to complete it. If you switch between production types (units, buildings and wonders), there is 50% shield penalty for the change, except at the Chieftain level.